# Inserting data in MySql Workbench

Tags: java

```
String query = "INSERT INTO 'registration'.'regg' ('fname','lname','address','gender','email','phone','username','password') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);" ;

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);

pst.setString(1, txtfname.getText());
pst.setString(2, txtlname.getText()); 
pst.setString(3, txtadd.getText()); 
pst.setString(4, cmbGender.getSelectedItem().toString()); 
pst.setString(5, txtEmail.getText());
pst.setString(6, txtphone.getText());enter code here
pst.setString(7, txtuser.getText());
pst.setString(8, txtpass.getText()); 

pst.executeUpdate();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Register successfully");
```

This is the error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''registration'.'regg'
>   ('fname','lname','address','gender','email','phone','usern' at line

Comment: First remove semicolon (;) and try, then also check `'registration'.'regg' `, single quotes are not required.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this

```
String query = "INSERT INTO regg (fname, lname, address, gender, email, phone, username, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Hope this will work for you